# Two foreach loops to be used in one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays:

```
$armortype = array(5,8);
```

and

```
$slotarray = array(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,16);
```

How do I combine these two in one foreach loop? Here's the code at the moment:

```
foreach($slotarray as $slot)
{
    foreach($armortype as $armor)
        $itempack = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE ItemLevel BETWEEN $formlevel1 AND $formlevel2 AND InventoryType =$slot AND Quality<5 AND AllowableClass in ('$formclass', '-1','2047','32767') AND Material=$armor ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    }
}
```

My $armor value doesn't come out right.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: What does "doesn't come out right" mean? Can you show the value of the  query? Also, order by rand is horribly inefficient and making multiple queries in loops is horribly inefficient.

Comment: `InventoryType in (", implode(',', $slotArray).") ....`

Comment: Well, how does `$armor` come out if it's wrong?

Comment: thanks Neal for the syntax highlight... but back to topic could you give more information about the table and give some example data. your flooding the database with unnecessary querys like this as

Comment: Do you want  each of your armorslots provided with 2 random armors of a specific type? 'cause then you shouldn't overwrite `$itempack`, but add to it (as an array for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
$itempack = mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM db
    WHERE ItemLevel BETWEEN $formlevel1 AND $formlevel2
        AND InventoryType = in ('". implode("', '", $slotarray) ."')
        AND Quality<5
        AND AllowableClass in ('$formclass', '-1','2047','32767')
        AND Material = in ('". implode("', '", $armortype) ."')
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1");
```

That should do it. Place it instead of both loops. It simply runs only one query instead of dozens of it...